# Showing all categories for every product for which it belongs to in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

how can i get the result as bellow in mysql?

I want to get all products group by id and show what categories it belongs to.
how can I get it in one sql ?
[image]

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `a`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `a`;
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `products_name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`products_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of a
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('1', 'hello');
INSERT INTO `a` VALUES ('2', 'world');




SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `b`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `b`;
CREATE TABLE `b` (
  `products_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `categories_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`products_id`,`categories_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of b
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `b` VALUES ('1', '1');
INSERT INTO `b` VALUES ('1', '2');
INSERT INTO `b` VALUES ('2', '1');
INSERT INTO `b` VALUES ('2', '3');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want?

```
SELECT a.products_id, a.products_name, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(b.categories_id,CHAR(8))) as products_to_categories
FROM a,b 
WHERE a.products_id = b.products_id
GROUP BY a.products_id, a.products_name
```

fiddle at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39edfc/3/0

Resulting image in fiddle

[image]

Comment: SELECT a.products_id, a.products_name, 
       group_concat(conv( oct( b.categories_id ) , 8, 10 )) as products_to_categories
from a,b 
where a.products_id = b.products_id
group by a.products_id, a.products_name

Comment: Edited it, GROUP_CONCAT expects string input

Comment: Glad that I could help

Comment: You should use a `join`.

Comment: This query isnt that complex, will it be significantly better, can you kindly explain why...

Comment: my sql is weak, I can not find how get this result ,and I cant search other questions similar to mine ,so I ask here

Comment: @mingfish_004 sorry that was a question to Shukiryu, about joins

Answer (score 1):

there are alternative way by using inner join, cheer =)

```
SELECT a.products_id, a.products_name,group_concat(b.categories_id)  
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON a.products_id = b.products_id
group by a.products_id, a.products_name
```